# Building Android Apps using Adobe AIR

Tags: android, flash, air

I am building an android application with Adobe Flash cs6 and Adobe AIR for the first time. Initially it looked good but later I faced a lot of problems. What I have till now is more of movieclip and less as3 coding. My app scales automatically according to different screen sizes. However since there are more movieclips my app somewhat lags in Kindle Fire. My question:
1. Do I need to convert my movie clips to Bitmaps or something? How is that done?
2. While converting to bitmap, do I need to specify width and height of the movieclips? Doesnt it get scaled automatically acc. to screen size?
Well, I am new to actionscript, AIR and stuff... so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All display objects have 'cacheAsBitmap' and 'cacheAsBitmapMatrix' propertiues that help with performance, but only for certain class of objects (primarily those not frequently changed).

More info: [Caching display objects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e35.html)

Also, make sure you have HW acceleration turned on for maximum benefit, especially on mobile: [HW acceleration](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS789ea67d3e73a8b2-5b45bb17124b3295cc8-7ff4.html)